# Why don't errors get returned when calling properties that don't exist?

Tags: powershell

Given the following snippet

```
$drives = Get-PSDrive

foreach($drive in $drives)
{
    Write-Host $drive.Name "`t" $drive.Root
    Write-Host " - " $drive.Free "`t" $drive.PropertyDoesntExist
}
```

The drive.PropertyDoesntExist property doesn't... erm... exist so I would expect an error to be thrown but instead it returns a null.

How can I get errors or exceptions?

EDIT - Me bad - I asked 2 questions in one so I moved one into a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902542/why-dont-errors-rasied-inside-get-spweb-get-propagated-to-powershell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [NextHop Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nexthop/archive/2011/03/21/psselectnonexistentproperties.aspx) provides a good solution to this problem. It doesn't give you an error, but instead a boolean. You can use `Get-Member` to get a collection of all of the real properties of the object's type and then match for your desired property.

Here's an example for strings:

```
PS C:\> $test = "I'm a string."
PS C:\> ($test | Get-Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -contains "Trim"
True
PS C:\> ($test | Get-Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -contains "Pigs"
False
```

If you explicitly want an error, you may want to look into [Set-Strictmode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx) as `Set-StrictMode -version 2` to trap non-existent properties. You can easily turn it off when you're done with it, too:

```
PS C:\> Set-StrictMode -version 2
PS C:\> "test".Pigs
Property 'Pigs' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:1 char:8
+ "test". <<<< Pigs
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (.:OperatorToken) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict

PS C:\> Set-StrictMode -off
```

Comment: Set-Strictmode is what I really wanted - tell me when I've made a typo damn you! ;) Any idea of how to get any exceptions raised by properties/methods

Comment: Not exactly - I am not really asking the right question. Assume $drive.Free above is valid but throws an exception (at least I know it does if called from .NET) - nothing appears in powershell. May be a quirk of Get-SPWeb - oh I've checked -ErrorAction. Maybe I'll ask a separate question.

Comment: Asked over here - really a separate q' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902542/why-dont-errors-rasied-inside-get-spweb-get-propagated-to-powershell