# Why don't errors rasied inside Get-SPWeb get propagated to powershell?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, powershell

If I have the following

```
$webs = Get-SPWeb -Limit all -ErrorAction Stop

foreach($web in $webs) 
{
    Write-Host $web.SiteUsers.xml 
}
```

I know that the same code in .NET will get an exception from `SPWeb.SiteUsers.xml` for one site on my server.

The actual exception or why isn't important - but running the code above I don't see any exceptions propogated or reported to PowerShell, $web.SiteUsers.xml just ruturns null on the site that errors.

Is this a powershell thing or a quirk of Get-SPWeb?

Comment: From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607807.aspx: `It is important to note that every site collection returned by the Get-SPWeb cmdlet is automatically disposed of at the end of the pipeline. To store the results of Get-SPWeb in a local variable, the Start-SPAssignment and Stop-SPAssignment cmdlets must be used to avoid memory leaks.` Therfor, $webs will be a collection of disposed objects once the cmdlet is finished.

Comment: @Eris Erm...yes. But that doesn't even begin to answer the question.

Comment: is `strict-mode` enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using property syntax, PowerShell will catch all exceptions.  If you want to see the exceptions, you'll need to use method syntax.  For example, instead of:

```
$web.SiteUsers
```

You would use:

```
$web.get_SiteUsers()
```

It would be nice if Set-StrictMode would let exceptions through, but it doesn't.

The primary reason for this behavior is related to formatting.  There are many commonly used properties that throw exceptions using the default formatting and cluttering up the output with error messages is definitely not the right thing to do.

That said, it seems reasonable for PowerShell to only catch exceptions while formatting output.  You can use the Microsoft Connect site to provide feedback.  For example, this item complains about this exact issue:  http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/533233/exceptions-thrown-in-property-getters-are-silently-ignored

Comment: That Connect link is broken - page not found (but with HTTP 500) - and the page doesn't seem to be on the Wayback Machine either.

Although if you go to http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/ and search "533233",  it does appear in the search results and you can see a snippet of the item there.