# Does PowerShell not rethrow a faulted Task's exception when accessing its Result property

Tags: powershell

On atleast PowerShell v4 (Server 2012R2) and v5 (Win10), it seems to return null when accessing the Result property of a faulted System.Threading.Tasks.Task object instead of throwing the exception that caused it to fault.

```bsh
$t = new-object System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource[int]
$t.SetException((New-Object System.Exception 'a'))

$t.Task.Result # No exception

$t.Task.Result -eq $null # True
```

The equivalent C# program does throw when accessing the Result getter, as indeed [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468) says it should:

> Note that, if an exception occurred during the operation of the task, or if the task has been cancelled, the Result property does not return a value. Instead, attempting to access the property value throws an AggregateException exception.

I can't find anything on the Internet about this behavior. Am I doing something wrong or does PS have some kind of special handling of the Result property?

---

Note that

```bsh
$t.Task.Wait() # Does throw the exception
```

does throw an AggregateException as it's supposed to.

---

Edit: I've now found [Why don't errors rasied inside Get-SPWeb get propagated to powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902542/why-dont-errors-rasied-inside-get-spweb-get-propagated-to-powershell) which this is a duplicate of. As PetSerAl said in this question's comments and the accepted answer of that question explains, PS suppresses exceptions from all getters and returns null instead.

Comment: `$t.Task.get_Result()`

Comment: Yeah, bypassing the getter that way does work. So it seems yes, PS has some special handing of the Result getter?

Comment: It is nothing specific to `Result` property. All property getters swallow exceptions, unless called as method.

Comment: Yes, looks like it. Confirmed with a class added with Add-Type. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't errors rasied inside Get-SPWeb get propagated to powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902542/why-dont-errors-rasied-inside-get-spweb-get-propagated-to-powershell)